# Can a flow which is initially supersonic, become subsonic without a shock wave?

Tags: supersonic, shock-waves

I am doing my college project in which air is first accelerated to supersonic  conditions in a nozzle. Then it is added into slow moving subsonic air. I see that my flow becomes supersonic and then subsonic but I don't see a shockwave. All this is done on Fluent using various 2 equation models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible . The shockless transition from supersonic to subsonic. It has been tested both experimentally and numerical solution. Read [this AIAA Paper](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.51438).

But in your case I would suggest you to be a bit cautious and recheck your mesh and boundary condition in CFD solver.